# using group by with inner join and count

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list all the details of `account_group_profile_test` which is in one to many relation with `account_group_physician_aff_t` table both contain `AMDM_ACCOUNT_GROUP_ID column` which is a Primary Key to `account_group_profile_test` table I want to display all the records of `account_group_profile_test` and count the number of records in `account_group_physician_aff_t` table which have same value in `AMDM_ACCOUNT_GROUP_ID column` (Foreign Key)

I am using following query but it is showing some error.

```
SELECT ag_pro.*, 
       Count(ag_phy_aff.account_group_physician_aff_id) 
FROM   account_group_profile_test ag_pro 
       inner join account_group_physician_aff_t ag_phy_aff 
               ON 
       ag_phy_aff.amdm_account_group_id = ag_pro.amdm_account_group_id 
GROUP  BY ag_pro.amdm_account_group_id
```

Comment: Which error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message has probably to do with the fact that you are trying to display all columns from the table `account_group_profile_test` (select `ag_pro.*`) but they are not listed in your GROUP BY clause.

You could do it as follows:
Select all records from `account_group_profile_test` with the count of the records in `account_group_physician_aff_t` that have a matching `amdm_account_group_id`

```
SELECT ag_pro.*, 
       (
           SELECT  count(*)
           FROM    account_group_physician_aff_t ag_phy_aff
           WHERE   ag_phy_aff.amdm_account_group_id = ag_pro.amdm_account_group_id
       ) "count of ag_phy_aff"
FROM   account_group_profile_test ag_pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the top part of your question, the following query should perform the correct action:

```
select ag_pro.*,
       X.aff_t_count
FROM account_group_profile_test ag_pro
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    amdm_account_group_id,
    count(*) as aff_t_count
    FROM account_group_physician_aff_t
    group by amdm_account_group_id
) X
on ag_pro.amdm_account_group_id = X.amdm_account_group_id
```

You only need the count of records in the `aff_t` table, so get that first by performing a sub-select, then join the results onto the full `ag_pro`  table.

This will only return values of `amdm_account_group_id` that are in both tables. To ensure that all values of that column are kept, even if they don't appear in the `aff_t` table, then replace the `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`, and deal with any `NULL` values by including a `CASE` block:

```
select ag_pro.*,
       CASE WHEN X.aff_t_count is NULL then 0
       ELSE X.aff_t_count 
       END as aff_t_count

FROM account_group_profile_test ag_pro
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    amdm_account_group_id,
    count(*) as aff_t_count
    FROM account_group_physician_aff_t
    group by amdm_account_group_id
) X
on ag_pro.amdm_account_group_id = X.amdm_account_group_id
```